# Ubuntu 17.10 no desktop icons

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, .desktop, desktop-icons

Ubuntu 17.10 (xorg), gnome 3.26.2.

After installing 17.10, there are no icons on the desktop.  I am unable to add anything to the desktop.

In the tweak tool all five switches for icons on the desktop are on.

In dconf I see this:

```
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true
org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
org.gnome.desktop.draw-background true
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?  I find nothing online that will help me.

Comment: The second one *should* do it, but apparently not. No clue if it is going anywhere, but did you do a fresh install, or upgrade?

Comment: Jacob Vlijm:  Upgrade from 17.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refreshing my HOME directory, cleaning out all kinds of old "junk" from it, paying special attention to cleaning out the .config directory.  I also created a new user so I could get a fresh copy of the .bashrc and .profile files.  This appears to have solved this (and another) problem.